# How to set working directory with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, unix, ubuntu, process, processbuilder

I am trying start a process in my home directory in ubuntu. I keep getting a permission denied exception and I have no idea why. Here is the code:

```
Process p = null;
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home");
p = pb.start();
```

Here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home": 

java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:475)
        at tester.Main.main(Main.java:30)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:164)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:81)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:468)
        ... 1 more
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You are trying to execute /home and it is not an executable file. The [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder-java.lang.String...-) argument of the process builder is the command to execute.

You want to set the working directory. You can that it via the [directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory-java.io.File-) method.

Here is a complete example:

```
Process p = null;
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("do_foo.sh");
pb.directory(new File("/home"));
p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just edited the question because I realized the mistake I made. I think you may have answered my other question as well

Comment: I had to use  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"sh","do_foo.sh"}); in order to make it work.

Comment: I had to use "sh -c ...":  Process process = new ProcessBuilder(['sh', '-c', "zip -r /tmp/$orderId /tmp/$orderId/".toString()]) (this is Groovy syntax)