# Run C++ executable from Java in Linux

Tags: java

How can I run a C++ executable "exerun" placed on Desktop from my Java Code in Linux. I found alot about Runtime but I cannot grab the concept clearly..Kindly Clear this out for me....

Comment: You may want to start by learning how to run *any* executable from a java vm. C++ has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: When you know that you need a class like `Runtime`, you should look up [that class in the Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) in order to read about its functionality: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("exerun.exe")`

Answer (score 4):

One should use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of `Runtime`

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg").start();
```

You can get the inputs stream, input error stream, and the output stream from `p`.
Then you can redirect the output of the process and provide it with input through java.

You should also take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405723/how-to-set-working-directory-with-processbuilder). It shows you how to set the working directory.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the `exec()` following the example below:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\path_to_the_file\\myfile.exe", null, new File("c:\\path_of_the_folder");
```

Here, you find 3 parameters:

- Location of your .exe
- The second parameter can be `null`
- The path of the directory with the *.exe file.

Comment: How do you get a `c:\\path_to_the_file\\myfile.exe` directory structure on Linux?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you need to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)`, where `command` is the command you want to execute.  This will return a `Process` object (say `myProcess`).

If your program produces output, you will need to continually read the streams you can retrieve with `myProcess.getInputStream()` and `myProcess.getErrorStream()`.  They correspond to the process's `stdout` and `stderr`, respectively.

If `myProcess` produces output and you don't read it from the Java program, `myProcess` will lockout after a while.