# Error in C++ program called from Java using JNI. Getting SEGV_ACCERR

Tags: java, c++, compiler-errors, java-native-interface, cross-compiling

Having trouble calling C++ code from JNI. The code runs in normal C++, but seems to have errors when I try to call it from Java and I think I'm compiling/linking things incorrectly. Can anyone spot what is wrong?

I'm cross compiling using the arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi toolkit to run the code on Beaglebone Black.

This is my *Makefile* for the C++ code:

```
PORT = arm12
CFLAGS = -D__cplusplus -Wall -O
CPP=/opt/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi-g++ -fPIC
CC=/opt/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi-gcc
INCPATH = -I./ -I../include -I./ -I../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/linux
LIBS =  -L../lib/$(PORT)

OBJS=   FingerVerification.o

SRCS=   FingerVerification.cpp

FDU03_TARGET = ../bin/$(PORT)/sgfplibtest_fdu03
FDU04_TARGET = ../bin/$(PORT)/sgfplibtest_fdu04
FDU05_TARGET = ../bin/$(PORT)/sgfplibtest_fdu05

all : $(FDU05_TARGET) $(FDU04_TARGET) $(FDU03_TARGET)

$(FDU05_TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    $(CPP) /opt/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/libusb.so -lpthread -lsgfpamx -lsgfdu05 -lsgfplib -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

$(FDU04_TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    $(CPP) /opt/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/libusb.so -lpthread -lsgfpamx -lsgfdu04 -lsgfplib -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

$(FDU03_TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    $(CPP) /opt/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/libusb.so  -lpthread -lsgfpamx -lsgfdu03 -lsgfplib -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

.cc.o :
    $(CPP) $(FLAGS) $(INCPATH) -c $<

.c.o :
    $(CPP) $(FLAGS) $(INCPATH) -c $<

.cpp.o :
    $(CPP) $(FLAGS) $(INCPATH) -c $<

dep :
    gccmakedep $(INCPATH) $(SRCS)

clean :
    rm -rf *.raw *.min $(OBJS) $(TARGET) core
    rm -rf $(PORT)
    mkdir $(PORT)
```

This is how the compilation for the C++ looks like:

```
/opt/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi-g++ -fPIC  -I./ -I../include -I./ -I../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -c FingerVerification.cpp
/opt/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi-g++ -fPIC /opt/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/libusb.so -lpthread -lsgfpamx -lsgfdu05 -lsgfplib -o ../bin/arm12/sgfplibtest_fdu05 FingerVerification.o -L../lib/arm12
/opt/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi-g++ -fPIC /opt/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/libusb.so -lpthread -lsgfpamx -lsgfdu04 -lsgfplib -o ../bin/arm12/sgfplibtest_fdu04 FingerVerification.o -L../lib/arm12
/opt/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi-g++ -fPIC /opt/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/libusb.so  -lpthread -lsgfpamx -lsgfdu03 -lsgfplib -o ../bin/arm12/sgfplibtest_fdu03 FingerVerification.o -L../lib/arm12
```

It outputs the FingerVerification.o along with executables that I won't be using with JNI (they are to run the original C++ code, but shouldn't be effecting the result).

After compiling the code and getting the .o file, I want to get the .so file (dynamic library) so I convert it like this:

```
/opt/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi-g++ /opt/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/libusb.so -lpthread -lsgfpamx -lsgfdu03 -lsgfplib FingerVerification.o -shared -o libFingerVerification.so -L../lib/arm12 -lc
```

When attempting to execute my Java program, I get an error midway in the execution of the C++ program (when it attempts to use a resource from the SDK). Here is the snippet:

```
Call CreateSGFPMObject()
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb6302d3c, pid=1007, tid=3057566832
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-arm )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libFingerVerification.so+0xd3c]  initializeResources()+0x74
```

Here is my Java code:

```
public class FingerVerification
{
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("FingerVerification");
    }
    public static native BiometricResult verifyUser(String filePathTemplate1,
        String filePathTemplate2);
    public static native void registerUser();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        registerUser();
        BiometricResult fingerResult = verifyUser("finger1.min", "finger2.min");
        //According to research, device resolution effects results by 20%, weight is 2
        //According to research, image quality based on acquisition area effects results by 73%, weight is 7.3
        double weight = fingerResult.getImgQuality() * 7.3 + fingerResult.getResolution() * 2;
        System.out.println("The weight is " + weight);
    }
}
```

My java code is successfully able to call a C++ native JNI method:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_FingerVerification_registerUser
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass thisClass)
```

This method quickly calls `initializeResources()`, which results in a crash

Here is the section of the C++ code it is crashing in:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "sgfplib.h"
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "FingerVerification.h"

LPSGFPM sgfplib = NULL;
SGDeviceInfoParam deviceInfo;
SGFingerInfo fingerInfo;
long err;
char function[100];
FILE *fp = NULL;

DWORD maxTemplateSize;
DWORD templateSize;
BYTE *templateToVerify;
BYTE *imgBuffer;

int initializeResources(void);
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
}

int initializeResources()
{
    //Creating the handle
    strcpy(function,"CreateSGFPMObject()");
    printf("\nCall %s\n",function);
    err = CreateSGFPMObject(&sgfplib);
    if (!sgfplib)
    {
        printf("ERROR - Unable to instantiate FPM object.\n\n");
        return false;
    }
    printf("%s returned: %ld\n",function,err);

    // Init()
    strcpy(function,"Init(SG_DEV_FDU03)");
    printf("\nCall %s\n",function);
    err = sgfplib->Init(SG_DEV_FDU03);
    printf("%s returned: %ld\n",function,err);
    if (err != SGFDX_ERROR_NONE)
    {
       printf("ERROR - Unable to initialize device.\n\n");
       return 0;
    }

    // OpenDevice()
    strcpy(function,"OpenDevice(0)");
    printf("\nCall %s\n",function);
    err = sgfplib->OpenDevice(0);
    printf("%s returned: %ld\n",function,err);

    // getDeviceInfo()
    deviceInfo.DeviceID = 0;
    strcpy(function,"GetDeviceInfo()");
    printf("\nCall %s\n",function);
    err = sgfplib->GetDeviceInfo(&deviceInfo);
    printf("%s returned: %ld\n",function,err);
    if (err == SGFDX_ERROR_NONE)
    {
      printf("\tdeviceInfo.DeviceID   : %ld\n", deviceInfo.DeviceID);
      printf("\tdeviceInfo.DeviceSN   : %s\n",  deviceInfo.DeviceSN);
      printf("\tdeviceInfo.ComPort    : %ld\n", deviceInfo.ComPort);
      printf("\tdeviceInfo.ComSpeed   : %ld\n", deviceInfo.ComSpeed);
      printf("\tdeviceInfo.ImageWidth : %ld\n", deviceInfo.ImageWidth);
      printf("\tdeviceInfo.ImageHeight: %ld\n", deviceInfo.ImageHeight);
      printf("\tdeviceInfo.Contrast   : %ld\n", deviceInfo.Contrast);
      printf("\tdeviceInfo.Brightness : %ld\n", deviceInfo.Brightness);
      printf("\tdeviceInfo.Gain       : %ld\n", deviceInfo.Gain);
      printf("\tdeviceInfo.ImageDPI   : %ld\n", deviceInfo.ImageDPI);
      printf("\tdeviceInfo.FWVersion  : %04X\n", (unsigned int) deviceInfo.FWVersion);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Note that it is doing the print statement correctly when it prints

> Call CreateSGFPMObject()

So it defiantely is executing the method up to the point when it needs to use a resource from the SecuGen SDK. This makes me think that I generated the libFingerVerification.so file incorrectly from the FingerVerification.o object file. Can anyone look over my work and see if there are any glaring issues?

Here is the complete stack trace

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xa8005d3c, pid=1104, tid=3057882224
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-arm )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libFingerVerification.so+0xd3c]  initializeResources()+0x74
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0xb6205428):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=1105, stack(0xb63ea000,0xb643a000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=2 (SEGV_ACCERR), si_addr=0xb6f10a8c

Registers:
  r0  = 0x00000000
  r1  = 0x0000012c
  r2  = 0x00000000
  r3  = 0xb6f10a8c
  r4  = 0xa8010340
  r5  = 0xa8006d58
  r6  = 0x00000000
  r7  = 0x00000000
  r8  = 0xb6438a94
  r9  = 0xb02fd0f8
  r10 = 0xb6205428
  fp  = 0xb6438a1c
  r12 = 0x00000000
  sp  = 0xb6438a10
  lr  = 0xa8005d2c
  pc  = 0xa8005d3c
  cpsr = 0xa00f0010

Top of Stack: (sp=0xb6438a10)
0xb6438a10:   a8010340 b6438a54 a8006d80 a8006d80
0xb6438a20:   b6205428 b02fd0f8 b6438a94 b6205550
0xb6438a30:   b6438b84 b6205668 b02fd0f8 b6718ecc
0xb6438a40:   b6205428 002fd3c8 b423cc80 b6438a8c
0xb6438a50:   b420c030 b420bf54 b6438a60 b42001e0
0xb6438a60:   b6438af4 b6438bd0 b6205428 b6438a6c
0xb6438a70:   00000000 b6438a94 b02fd3c8 00000000
0xb6438a80:   b02fd0f8 00000000 b6438a98 b6438ab8 

Instructions: (pc=0xa8005d3c)
0xa8005d1c:   e59f345c e7943003 e1a00003 ebffff78
0xa8005d2c:   e1a03000 e1a02003 e59f3448 e7943003
0xa8005d3c:   e5832000 e59f3438 e7943003 e5933000
0xa8005d4c:   e3530000 1a000005 e59f342c e0843003 

Register to memory mapping:

  r0  = 0x00000000
0x00000000 is an unknown value

  r1  = 0x0000012c
0x0000012c is an unknown value

  r2  = 0x00000000
0x00000000 is an unknown value

  r3  = 0xb6f10a8c
0xb6f10a8c: err+0 in /lib/libc.so.6 at 0xb6e47000

  r4  = 0xa8010340
0xa8010340: <offset 0xb340> in /home/root/Desktop/BioFlip/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/JNI/libFingerVerification.so at 0xa8005000

  r5  = 0xa8006d58
0xa8006d58: Java_FingerVerification_registerUser+0 in /home/root/Desktop/BioFlip/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/JNI/libFingerVerification.so at 0xa8005000

  r6  = 0x00000000
0x00000000 is an unknown value

  r7  = 0x00000000
0x00000000 is an unknown value

  r8  = 0xb6438a94
0xb6438a94 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0xb6205428

  r9  = 0xb02fd0f8
0xb02fd0f8 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}

  r10 = 0xb6205428
0xb6205428 is a thread

  fp  = 0xb6438a1c
0xb6438a1c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0xb6205428

  r12 = 0x00000000
0x00000000 is an unknown value

  sp  = 0xb6438a10
0xb6438a10 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0xb6205428

  lr  = 0xa8005d2c
0xa8005d2c: _Z19initializeResourcesv+0x64 in /home/root/Desktop/BioFlip/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/JNI/libFingerVerification.so at 0xa8005000

  pc  = 0xa8005d3c
0xa8005d3c: _Z19initializeResourcesv+0x74 in /home/root/Desktop/BioFlip/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/JNI/libFingerVerification.so at 0xa8005000



Stack: [0xb63ea000,0xb643a000],  sp=0xb6438a10,  free space=314k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libFingerVerification.so+0xd3c]  initializeResources()+0x74

[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xb]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  FingerVerification.registerUser()V+0
j  FingerVerification.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+0
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0xb626bea8 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1111, stack(0xa7d40000,0xa7d90000)]
  0xb626a320 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1110, stack(0xa7d90000,0xa7e10000)]
  0xb6268d60 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1109, stack(0xa7e10000,0xa7e60000)]
  0xb625a140 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1108, stack(0xa7e60000,0xa7eb0000)]
  0xb6257cc8 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1107, stack(0xa7eb0000,0xa7f00000)]
=>0xb6205428 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=1105, stack(0xb63ea000,0xb643a000)]

Other Threads:
  0xb62566c8 VMThread [stack: 0xa8011000,0xa8091000] [id=1106]
  0xb620e928 WatcherThread [stack: 0xa7cc0000,0xa7d40000] [id=1112]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 2432K, used 321K [0xa8380000, 0xa8620000, 0xaad80000)
  eden space 2176K,  14% used [0xa8380000, 0xa83d0610, 0xa85a0000)
  from space 256K,   0% used [0xa85a0000, 0xa85a0000, 0xa85e0000)
  to   space 256K,   0% used [0xa85e0000, 0xa85e0000, 0xa8620000)
 tenured generation   total 5376K, used 0K [0xaad80000, 0xab2c0000, 0xb0180000)
   the space 5376K,   0% used [0xaad80000, 0xaad80000, 0xaad80200, 0xab2c0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 1528K [0xb0180000, 0xb0d80000, 0xb4180000)
   the space 12288K,  12% used [0xb0180000, 0xb02fe0f8, 0xb02fe200, 0xb0d80000)
No shared spaces configured.

Card table byte_map: [0xa8320000,0xa8380000] byte_map_base: 0xa7dde400

Polling page: 0xb6fec000

Code Cache  [0xb4200000, 0xb4298000, 0xb6200000)
 total_blobs=132 nmethods=4 adapters=66 free_code_cache=32186Kb largest_free_block=32958784

Compilation events (8 events):
Event: 0.710 Thread 0xb626a320    1             java.lang.String::indexOf (70 bytes)
Event: 0.719 Thread 0xb626a320 nmethod 1 0xb4290848 code [0xb4290940, 0xb4290aa4]
Event: 0.730 Thread 0xb626a320    2             java.lang.String::hashCode (55 bytes)
Event: 0.732 Thread 0xb626a320 nmethod 2 0xb4290cc8 code [0xb4290db0, 0xb4290ea8]
Event: 0.739 Thread 0xb626a320    3             java.lang.String::charAt (29 bytes)
Event: 0.741 Thread 0xb626a320 nmethod 3 0xb4290f48 code [0xb4291040, 0xb4291164]
Event: 0.744 Thread 0xb626a320    4             sun.nio.cs.US_ASCII$Encoder::encode (107 bytes)
Event: 0.748 Thread 0xb626a320 nmethod 4 0xb4291248 code [0xb4291330, 0xb4291518]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (3 events):
Event: 0.465 Thread 0xb6205428 Threw 0xa838f760 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-arm-vfp-sflt/jdk7u51/527/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:3991
Event: 0.736 Thread 0xb6205428 Threw 0xa83c1ed0 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-arm-vfp-sflt/jdk7u51/527/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.784 Thread 0xb6205428 Threw 0xa83c79d8 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-arm-vfp-sflt/jdk7u51/527/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.777 loading class 0xa82e5fd0
Event: 0.777 loading class 0xa82e5fd0 done
Event: 0.778 loading class 0xa82bb0a8
Event: 0.778 loading class 0xa82bb0a8 done
Event: 0.783 loading class 0xb62783f8
Event: 0.783 loading class 0xb62783f8 done
Event: 0.787 loading class 0xa82a6420
Event: 0.787 loading class 0xa82a6420 done
Event: 0.788 loading class 0xa82a6e60
Event: 0.789 loading class 0xa82a6e60 done


Dynamic libraries:
00008000-00009000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 50621      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java
00010000-00011000 rw-p 00000000 b3:02 50621      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java
00011000-00032000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
a7b3c000-a7bf0000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 29792      /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
a7bf0000-a7bf7000 ---p 000b4000 b3:02 29792      /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
a7bf7000-a7bfb000 r--p 000b3000 b3:02 29792      /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
a7bfb000-a7bfd000 rw-p 000b7000 b3:02 29792      /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
a7bfd000-a7c03000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a7c0f000-a7c1e000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 50007      /home/root/Desktop/BioFlip/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/lib/arm12/libsgfplib.so
a7c1e000-a7c25000 ---p 0000f000 b3:02 50007      /home/root/Desktop/BioFlip/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/lib/arm12/libsgfplib.so
a7c25000-a7c26000 rw-p 0000e000 b3:02 50007      /home/root/Desktop/BioFlip/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/lib/arm12/libsgfplib.so
a7c26000-a7c41000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 50005      /home/root/Desktop/BioFlip/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/lib/arm12/libsgfdu03.so
a7c41000-a7c48000 ---p 0001b000 b3:02 50005      /home/root/Desktop/BioFlip/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/lib/arm12/libsgfdu03.so
a7c48000-a7c96000 rw-p 0001a000 b3:02 50005      /home/root/Desktop/BioFlip/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/lib/arm12/libsgfdu03.so
a7c96000-a7ca6000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 49994      /home/root/Desktop/BioFlip/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/lib/arm12/libsgfpamx.so
a7ca6000-a7caf000 rw-p 00010000 b3:02 49994      /home/root/Desktop/BioFlip/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/lib/arm12/libsgfpamx.so
a7caf000-a7cb7000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 50002      /home/root/Desktop/BioFlip/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/lib/arm12/libusb-0.1.so.4
a7cb7000-a7cbe000 ---p 00008000 b3:02 50002      /home/root/Desktop/BioFlip/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/lib/arm12/libusb-0.1.so.4
a7cbe000-a7cc0000 rw-p 00007000 b3:02 50002      /home/root/Desktop/BioFlip/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/lib/arm12/libusb-0.1.so.4
a7cc0000-a7cc1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
a7cc1000-a7d90000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:1111]
a7d90000-a7d91000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
a7d91000-a7f00000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:1107]
a7f00000-a7f21000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a7f21000-a8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
a8005000-a8009000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 50016      /home/root/Desktop/BioFlip/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/JNI/libFingerVerification.so
a8009000-a8010000 ---p 00004000 b3:02 50016      /home/root/Desktop/BioFlip/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/JNI/libFingerVerification.so
a8010000-a8011000 rw-p 00003000 b3:02 50016      /home/root/Desktop/BioFlip/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/JNI/libFingerVerification.so
a8011000-a8012000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
a8012000-a8091000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:1106]
a8091000-a80dc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a80dc000-a829a000 r--s 039e1000 b3:02 50694      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/rt.jar
a829a000-a82f8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a82f8000-a8320000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a8320000-a8322000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a8322000-a8335000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a8335000-a8338000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a8338000-a835f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a835f000-a8365000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a8365000-a837f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a837f000-a8620000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a8620000-aad80000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
aad80000-ab2c0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ab2c0000-b0180000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b0180000-b0d80000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b0d80000-b4180000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4180000-b4183000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4183000-b4200000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4200000-b4298000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
b4298000-b627c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b627c000-b6300000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6308000-b630f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b630f000-b6329000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6329000-b633f000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 50678      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/arm/libzip.so
b633f000-b6346000 ---p 00016000 b3:02 50678      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/arm/libzip.so
b6346000-b6347000 rw-p 00015000 b3:02 50678      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/arm/libzip.so
b6347000-b6352000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 46765      /lib/libnss_files-2.16.so
b6352000-b6359000 ---p 0000b000 b3:02 46765      /lib/libnss_files-2.16.so
b6359000-b635a000 r--p 0000a000 b3:02 46765      /lib/libnss_files-2.16.so
b635a000-b635b000 rw-p 0000b000 b3:02 46765      /lib/libnss_files-2.16.so
b635b000-b6364000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 46689      /lib/libnss_nis-2.16.so
b6364000-b636b000 ---p 00009000 b3:02 46689      /lib/libnss_nis-2.16.so
b636b000-b636c000 r--p 00008000 b3:02 46689      /lib/libnss_nis-2.16.so
b636c000-b636d000 rw-p 00009000 b3:02 46689      /lib/libnss_nis-2.16.so
b636d000-b637e000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 46771      /lib/libnsl-2.16.so
b637e000-b6385000 ---p 00011000 b3:02 46771      /lib/libnsl-2.16.so
b6385000-b6386000 r--p 00010000 b3:02 46771      /lib/libnsl-2.16.so
b6386000-b6387000 rw-p 00011000 b3:02 46771      /lib/libnsl-2.16.so
b6387000-b6389000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6389000-b638f000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 46541      /lib/libnss_compat-2.16.so
b638f000-b6397000 ---p 00006000 b3:02 46541      /lib/libnss_compat-2.16.so
b6397000-b6398000 r--p 00006000 b3:02 46541      /lib/libnss_compat-2.16.so
b6398000-b6399000 rw-p 00007000 b3:02 46541      /lib/libnss_compat-2.16.so
b6399000-b63bf000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 50684      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/arm/libjava.so
b63bf000-b63c7000 ---p 00026000 b3:02 50684      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/arm/libjava.so
b63c7000-b63c8000 rw-p 00026000 b3:02 50684      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/arm/libjava.so
b63c8000-b63d2000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 50650      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/arm/libverify.so
b63d2000-b63da000 ---p 0000a000 b3:02 50650      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/arm/libverify.so
b63da000-b63db000 rw-p 0000a000 b3:02 50650      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/arm/libverify.so
b63db000-b63e1000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 46539      /lib/librt-2.16.so
b63e1000-b63e8000 ---p 00006000 b3:02 46539      /lib/librt-2.16.so
b63e8000-b63e9000 r--p 00005000 b3:02 46539      /lib/librt-2.16.so
b63e9000-b63ea000 rw-p 00006000 b3:02 46539      /lib/librt-2.16.so
b63ea000-b63eb000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b63eb000-b643a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:1105]
b643a000-b64a2000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 47878      /lib/libm-2.16.so
b64a2000-b64a9000 ---p 00068000 b3:02 47878      /lib/libm-2.16.so
b64a9000-b64aa000 r--p 00067000 b3:02 47878      /lib/libm-2.16.so
b64aa000-b64ab000 rw-p 00068000 b3:02 47878      /lib/libm-2.16.so
b64ab000-b69d8000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 50654      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/arm/client/libjvm.so
b69d8000-b69df000 ---p 0052d000 b3:02 50654      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/arm/client/libjvm.so
b69df000-b6a04000 rw-p 0052c000 b3:02 50654      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/arm/client/libjvm.so
b6a04000-b6e21000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6e21000-b6e3f000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 47882      /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b6e3f000-b6e46000 ---p 0001e000 b3:02 47882      /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b6e46000-b6e47000 rw-p 0001d000 b3:02 47882      /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b6e47000-b6f6b000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 48400      /lib/libc-2.16.so
b6f6b000-b6f72000 ---p 00124000 b3:02 48400      /lib/libc-2.16.so
b6f72000-b6f74000 r--p 00123000 b3:02 48400      /lib/libc-2.16.so
b6f74000-b6f75000 rw-p 00125000 b3:02 48400      /lib/libc-2.16.so
b6f75000-b6f78000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6f78000-b6f7a000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 48387      /lib/libdl-2.16.so
b6f7a000-b6f81000 ---p 00002000 b3:02 48387      /lib/libdl-2.16.so
b6f81000-b6f82000 r--p 00001000 b3:02 48387      /lib/libdl-2.16.so
b6f82000-b6f83000 rw-p 00002000 b3:02 48387      /lib/libdl-2.16.so
b6f83000-b6f96000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 50582      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/lib/arm/jli/libjli.so
b6f96000-b6f9e000 ---p 00013000 b3:02 50582      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/lib/arm/jli/libjli.so
b6f9e000-b6f9f000 rw-p 00013000 b3:02 50582      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/lib/arm/jli/libjli.so
b6f9f000-b6fb3000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 48680      /lib/libpthread-2.16.so
b6fb3000-b6fba000 ---p 00014000 b3:02 48680      /lib/libpthread-2.16.so
b6fba000-b6fbb000 r--p 00013000 b3:02 48680      /lib/libpthread-2.16.so
b6fbb000-b6fbc000 rw-p 00014000 b3:02 48680      /lib/libpthread-2.16.so
b6fbc000-b6fbe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6fc2000-b6fca000 rw-s 00000000 00:16 7747       /tmp/hsperfdata_root/1104
b6fca000-b6fe9000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 48402      /lib/ld-2.16.so
b6feb000-b6fec000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6fec000-b6fed000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6fed000-b6ff0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6ff0000-b6ff1000 r--p 0001e000 b3:02 48402      /lib/ld-2.16.so
b6ff1000-b6ff2000 rw-p 0001f000 b3:02 48402      /lib/ld-2.16.so
bebcc000-bebed000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
ffff0000-ffff1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vectors]

VM Arguments:
java_command: FingerVerification
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/ejre1.7.0_51/
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/:/usr/java/ejre1.7.0_51/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:../lib/arm12
SHELL=/bin/sh
```

Thank you.

Comment: What does CreateSGFPMObject() do and what is the typedef for sgfplib?  I am not immediately seeing anything wrong with what you have there, could there be an issue in the CreateSGFPMObject method or the way things are being called from Java_FingerVerification_verifyUser?  How are you handling the JStrings javaFpTemplate1 and javaFpTemplate2?

Comment: Well I create CreateSGFPMObject() is defined in sgfplib and is a handler to communicate with the fingerprint scanner I am using. The sgfplib is basically the SecuGen SDK that defines these methods. I don't think there is anything wrong with the method because if I would run this code not in JNI and in pure C++ it works just fine. javaFpTemplate1 and javaFpTemplate2 are eventually turned into char* and represent file paths that store the fingerprint template. The code doesn't get close to there though, so that isn't the problem. The error occurs in the initializeResource() method.

Comment: Basically, the fact that the code I have it working in native C++ (it works if I run the /bin/arm12/sgfplibtest_fdu03 it makes and called initializeResource() in the C++ main function) makes me believe that the way I'm compiling/linking it with JNI is the issue. I basically just generated my JNI header and then copy pasted the C++ code over and only handling the "j" parameters.

Comment: As far I as I can tell, there isn't anything wrong with the way your compiling.  The fact that it works as a native program but not in Java suggests that you either botched something in the JNI portion or your experiencing some kind of thread or type safety issue, however, it's impossible to tell with the info provided.  Do you have a complete stack trace?  Do you have the src code for CreateSGFPMObject?  You're probably going to need to connect the debugger directly to the JVM for this one ;(

Comment: Hey, I just posted the .log file if that is what you need. I don't have the source code for CreateSGFPMObject as the code is in the SDKs library files that I include when I compile and generate FingerVerification.o. This part here: /opt/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi-g++ /opt/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/libusb.so -lpthread -lsgfpamx -lsgfdu03 -lsgfplib

Comment: Well SEGV_ACCERR looks like its a possible permission issue.  Is java running under a different user than your C test program?

Comment: Umm I compiled the code on Ubuntu using the arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi toolkit and then I send the binaries over to the beaglebone (an ARM based device) to be run. This works fine when doing it with the native C++ code. Java is platform independent so I just build it using jvac as normal. The main method in the java program does run because it calls the Java_FingerVerification_registerUser
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass thisClass), which then calls the intializeResources() method. I guess I can try giving everything max permissions with chmod 755 and see what happens.

Comment: I don't think changing permissions did anything. Still getting an error with SEGV_ACCERR in the THREAD part of the log.

Comment: I don't know why this may matter, but you call `CreateSGFPMObject()` with an address of a global variable. It could be worth checking if the error persists when you use a local address.

Comment: Its not that kind of a permission issue.  So I assume your figure print scanner is attached via usb to the beaglebone.  The driver for that thing probably created some /dev/input/... object that CreateSGFPMObject is trying to attach to.  For some reason your JVM process does not have permission to attach to that device.  Unless the docuemntation tells you what CreateSGFPMObject is trying to do, you will need to [attach GDB to the JVM via pid](http://returntojava.blogspot.com/2008/11/overcome-java-jni-gdb-errors-on.html) to try and figure out what it is getting stuck on.

Comment: When I try to do the GDB debugging I get the error Cannot access memory at address 0xb6f0c0c8. Do you know how I would go about giving the JVM permissions to access the driver's objects? I mean even if I did debug I don't have access to the source code of the SDK, just the .so files of the library. Thus, I can't really change anything. Would trying JNA or another method to access C++ work better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I basically gave up on this. Instead of using JNI I decided to run the executable created by compiling native C++ code through Java using a similar method to this:

[Run C++ executable from Java in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625611/run-c-executable-from-java-in-linux/18625697#18625697)

I'm planning to just pass in arguments into the main method of the C++ code that will determine which function to call and any result returned by a function will just be saved into a temporary file that the java program can read and then delete. Hacky, but simpler and it should work. The C++ integration is just a small component of the system I was forced to use anyway.