# youtube-dl converts "C:\" to "C#\" when setting save location

Tags: java, swing, youtube-dl

I am creating a Java based GUI for the Windows exe version of [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) .
The **OUTPUT TEMPLATE** portion of the README says that `-o` can be used to set the save location and file name while downloading.
When I use the program through command line, I can set the download location as normal using `youtube-dl.exe -o "C:\Users\<user>\Videos\%(title)s.%(ext)s" <youtube-link>` and it downloads as normal to the specified folder.
However, when I am calling the process through Java, using `ProcessBuilder` as follows:

```
output = "-o \"" + save_path + "\\%(title)s.%(ext)s\"";
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("lib\\youtube-dl.exe", output, url.getText()).start();
```

I keep getting the following output:

```
-o "C:\Users\nightstalker\Videos\youtube-dl\%(title)s.%(ext)s"
Thread Start
[youtube] wnc77S-g0qQ: Downloading webpage
[youtube] wnc77S-g0qQ: Extracting video information
[youtube] wnc77S-g0qQ: Downloading js player en_US-vfljL8ofl
[youtube] wnc77S-g0qQ: Downloading DASH manifest
[download] Destination:  C#\Users\nightstalker\Videos\youtube-dl\Some Video.mp4
```

This is what `save_path` looks like

```
File save_path = new File("C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\Videos\\youtube-dl");
```

This basically creates a folder called `C#\Users\nightstalker\Videos\youtube-dl` and continues to download there.
Any reason why?

Comment: What does `save_path` look like? And/or is it somehow processed before?

Comment: So if you output `save_path` or `output`, is the hash already there or is it converted only within youtube-dl?

Comment: Converted with `youtube-dl`. The first line in the output is the `output` variable being printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to sidestep the formatting problem and hopefully provide an answer that still works for you.

**ProcessBuilder** lets you set the working directory as follows:

> ```
> Process p = null;
> ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("do_foo.sh");
> pb.directory("/home");
> p = pb.start();
> ```
>
> Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8405745/154527

Instead of putting the whole path into the **-o** option passed to **youtube-dl** you can set the **directory()** on the **ProcessBuilder** to **C:\Users\<user>\Videos** as follows:

```
output = "\"%(title)s.%(ext)s\"";
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("lib\\youtube-dl.exe", "-o", output, url.getText()).directory("save_path").start();
```

Comment: The thing with `youtube-dl` is that it will start downloading directly to the folder in which it is kept. So, this method will just change working directory and not save path for `youtube-dl`.  
Still, let me give it a try.

Comment: Are you being bitten by this Windows-specific filename encoding bug: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/4787

Comment: your answer was perfect. Thanks for enlightening me about `ProcessBuilder`.
Did away with `-o` parameter completely, just using the `directory()` option of `ProcessBuilder`.
Much thanks!

Comment: Great stuff.  I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Downvoter, come explain your grievance. I can't fix what I don't know.  I addressed an issue with handing the -o switch and its value in a single parameter to the process.  That could potentially have been your issue.