# java code to execute commands

Tags: java, command, tabula

I want to execute tabula tool commands,from within the java program. The code that I am trying is:

```
System.setProperty("user.dir", "C:\\Program Files");
String command ="\\tabula\\tabula-0.9.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar "+"D:\\sample.pdf"+" -o "+"D:\\sampleeeee.csv";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

it is not working,any help would be appreciated.
[this command need to be executed from java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OojOz.jpg)

Comment: That first statement isn't going to change your (or a child process') working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to set the working directory where the command will run.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8405745/1364747

```
Process p = null;
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java","-jar","tabula-0.9.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar", "D:\\sample.pdf", "-o", "D:\\sampleeeee.csv");
pb.directory("C:\\Program Files\\tabula");
p = pb.start();
```

Comment: In the above code i am getting error like,  Cannot run program "tabula-0.9.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"       can u help me out with this, thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure the command you had shown in the picture works from your command line prompt? Your full command could be something like this: java -jar tabula-0.9.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar D:\\sample.pdf -o D:\\sampleeeee.csv

Comment: yes it works without "java -jar" in command line.if i include java -jar in code then also it is not executing

Comment: Java and -jar have to be two separate strings like this: new ProcessBuilder("java","-jar","tabula-0.9.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar", "D:\\sample.pdf", "-o", "D:\\sampleeeee.csv");

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the working directory when calling `exec`:

```
Path workingDir = Paths.get("C:\\Program Files\\tabula");

String[] command = {
    "tabula-0.9.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar",
    "sample.pdf",
    "-o samk.csv"
};

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, workingDir.toFile());
```

Comment: while running above code getting errorCannot run program "tabula-0.9.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar" (in directory "C:\Program Files\tabula"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)