# Setting working directory for ProcessBuilder is not working

Tags: java, runtime, processbuilder

I am trying to run a file called test.pdf which is located at C:/Software/ using ProcessBuilder. Following is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

         ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("test.pdf");
         pb.directory(new File("C:/Software/"));
         pb.start();

    }
```

And I'm getting the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "test.pdf" (in directory "C:\Software"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

I checked this [How to set working directory with ProcessBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405723/how-to-set-working-directory-with-processbuilder/8405745) thread in stackoverflow. But didn't have any luck. Can anyone help on this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code :

```
        String fileToOpen = "test.pdf";
        List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
        command.add("rundll32.exe");
        command.add("url.dll,FileProtocolHandler");
        command.add(fileToOpen);

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
        builder.directory(new File("C://Software//"));
        builder.command(command);

        builder.start();
```

It will open your pdf .
Just change the file name if you want to open other file in same directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my intention is to change the current working directory to other directory so that I can execute some commands from that directory. That's why I used ProcessBuilder.

Comment: updated answer fro opening pdf using ProcessBuilder.