How to handle zombie processes？
When I use the method of java.lang.Process to execute a command, if there is an unexpected situation, such as executing 'cd /tmp/git && git clone xxxx', the parent directory is deleted, and then a zombie process is left behind. Why?
I tried to terminate the zombie process by 'process.destroy()' in the code, or delete the zombie process directly from the command line using the kill command, but none of them worked. Is there any way to prevent zombie process from occurring, or to handle it after they occur?
My code
public static ShellResult executeAndGetExitStatus(String command) {
    ShellResult result = new ShellResult();
    long timeout = getTimeoutInCmd(command);//it is usually 600 seconds
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    Integer exitStatus = -1;

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", command);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process = null;
    try {
        process = pb.start();

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
            out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

            // check
            if (System.nanoTime() - startTime > TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(timeout)) {
                process.destroyForcibly(); // timeout,stop process
                throw new InterruptedException("Command execution timed out " + timeout);
            }
        }

        boolean exitInTime;
        try {
            exitInTime = process.waitFor(timeout - (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1_000_000_000,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // interrupted,try stop it again
            process.destroyForcibly();
            throw e;
        }

        if (!exitInTime) {
            process.destroyForcibly();
            throw new InterruptedException("Command execution timed out " + timeout);
        }

        exitStatus = process.exitValue();

    } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("excute shell error, defaultTimeout: {}, command:{}", timeout, command, e);
    } finally {
        if (process != null && process.isAlive()) {
            process.destroyForcibly(); // stop it
        }
    }

    result.setOut(out.toString().trim());
    result.setExitStatus(exitStatus);
    logger.debug("execute shell defaultTimeout: {}, command: {}, out: {}, status: {}", timeout, command, out, exitStatus);

    return result;
}


Presumably the zombie process is git? If so, try changing to exec git clone xxx, so that you are waiting on it directly.

Not entirely related to your problem but is there a reason why you are not setting the working directory with the ProcessBuilder? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405723/how-to-set-working-directory-with-processbuilder

What error(s) are you getting? A zombie process is the one that has terminated but has not been waited for by its parent. If that's your child process, you need to wait for it. If that's yout grandchild process, the grandparent can do nothing about it, you need to fix your child.

@user207421 Assuming my command is cd /tmp/git && git clone xxxx, deleting the /tmp/git  directory during execution will result in a zombie process like this: `[root@172 ~]# ps -eo pid,ppid,lstart,cmd | grep defunct
1372455 2407647 Wed May  8 10:52:11 2024 [git-remote-http] `

@n.m.could  I used process.waitFor() and process.destroyForcible() in the code to destroy it, but it's diden't work, the zombie process still generated and could not be deleted.

Maybe this is helpful.

@n.m.could Thank you for your answer,but this only used for commands with a very large output stream (std output), it is not applicable to me.
